# Historical monthly farm/agricultural data 1950 to the present

Tags: data-request, economics, prices, historical

I would like to find machine readable monthly data going back to at least 1950 relating to farming and agriculture.
Of particular interest are

- commodity prices for core commodities: corn, wheat, beef ...
- aggregate commodity price indexes
- production levels
- measures of "value created" something like GDP for agriculture
- farm foreclosures

I am most interested in numbers that a broad range of people actually pay attention to.

Comment: For the whole world?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul either US and/or the whole world. Farm foreclosures mainly make sense for US.

Comment: Ehh. Have you tried the USDA NASS site?

Comment: @DeerHunter Had not heard of it until now :) Thanks! Glad I asked.

Comment: Daniel, if not a secret, what kind of research is it? I'm currently trying to look into relations between commodity prices and farm bankruptcies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "FOOD AND AGRICULTURE ORGANIZATION OF THE UNITED NATIONS - Statistics Division" ([link](https://www.fao.org/faostat/en/#data)) provides historical data for commodity prices and agricultural production.

You can download for a single country or for all countries. Some data sets go back to at least the 1960s. You'll have to investigate which data sets may be best suited to your purpose.

Data formats are typically zipped CSV.

[image]